# How to get jQuery Simple Slider to show initial value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to get the jQuery Simple Slider (http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/) to initialse a span that shows the slider value before it is dragged. The span does get updated as soon as the slider is dragged and the code to update the span is in the same bind, so it looks to me like the slider:changed event gets caught but the slider:ready doesn't.

```
<form>
    <input name="slider" 
           type="text" 
           data-slider="true" 
           data-slider-highlight="true" 
           data-slider-step="1" 
           data-slider-range="1,99" 
           value="20">  
</form>



$("[data-slider]")
    .each(function () {
        var range;
        var input = $(this);
        $("<span>").addClass("output")
            .insertAfter(input);
        range = input.data("slider-range").split(",");
        $("<span>").addClass("range")
            .html(range[0])
            .insertBefore(input);
        $("<span>").addClass("range")
            .html(range[1])
            .insertAfter(input);
        $(this).bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
            $(this).nextAll(".output:first")
                .html(data.value.toFixed(2));
        })
    });
```

However, the [examples](http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/demo.html) given by the simpleslider author do appear to show the initial slider values, but I just can't see what I'm doing differently that prevents mine working.

Please see my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/nickweavers/77c89pju/23/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the value for first time manually, i think that's the simpler approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/77c89pju/26/

The code i write in the end of the anonymous function called in each loop of "data-slider" is:

`$(this).nextAll(".output:first").html($(this).val());`

Comment: Thanks @starless. This is a pragmatic solution. However, I'd still like to understand why the event slider:ready isn't getting caught. When I breakpoint the line that triggers the event in Firebug, I can see it gets executed. Unfortunately my javascripts skills aren't strong enough to figure why the handler doesn't see it.

Comment: Sorry, I misundertood the question. Is strange i think it has to do with the execution order of JavaScript or something because, if you wrap the JavaScript code you wrote and wrap it inside <script></script> tag and you put it after input element it works fine. Look here http://jsfiddle.net/77c89pju/27/